# Why isnt the .clearRect function working properly?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

So im making this space invaders game in javascript. My problem right now is that when the enemies move left and right they dont clear rect so you can see thier footage as shown here:
[image]

I just wanted to know what i could fix to solve this problem. I would love if you could help here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Space Invaders</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  canvas{
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background: transparent;
  }
  #backgroundCanvas{
   background-color: black;
  }

  </style>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="backgroundCanvas" width="550" height="600"></canvas>
<canvas id="playerCanvas" width="550" height="600"></canvas>
<canvas id="enemiesCanvas" width="550" height="600"></canvas>

   <script>
   (function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var game = {};

      game.stars = [];
      game.width = 550;
      game.height = 600;
      game.images = [];

      game.doneImages = 0;
      game.requiredImages = 0;
      game.keys = [];
      game.enemies = [];

      game.count = 0;
      game.division = 48;
      game.left = false;
      game.enemySpeed = 3;

      game.contextBackground = document.getElementById("backgroundCanvas").getContext('2d');

      game.contextPlayer = document.getElementById("playerCanvas").getContext('2d');

      game.contextEnemies = document.getElementById("enemiesCanvas").getContext('2d');

      game.player = {
        x:  game.width / 2 -50,
        y:  game.height - 110,
        width:100,
        height:100,
        speed: 3,
        rendered: false
      }




      $(document).keydown(function(e){
        game.keys[e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which] = true;

      })
      $(document).keyup(function(e){
       delete game.keys[e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which];

      })

      /*
      up -38
      down-40
      left -37
      right-39
      w-87
      a-65
      s-83
      d-68
      space-32
    */

      function init(){
        for(i=0; i<600;i++){
          game.stars.push({
            x:Math.floor(Math.random()* game.width),
            y:Math.floor(Math.random()* game.height),
            size: Math.random()*5
          })
        }

        for(y=0;y<5;y++){
          for(x =0;x<5;x++){
             game.enemies.push({
              x: (x*70) + (70*x) + 10,
              y: (y*70) + (10*y) + 40,
              width:70,
              height: 70,
              image:1
             })
          }
        }


        loop();
      }
      function addStars(num){
          for(i=0; i<num;i++){
            game.stars.push({
              x:Math.floor(Math.random()* game.width),
              y:game.height+10,
              size: Math.random()*5
            })
          }

      }
      function update(){
         addStars(1);
         game.count++;
           for(i in game.stars){
            if(game.stars[i].y <= -5){
                game.stars.splice(i,1);
            }
            game.stars[i].y--;
           }

           if(game.keys[37] || game.keys[65]){
            if(game.player.x>=0){
              game.player.x-=game.player.speed;
              game.player.rendered = false;
            }

           }
          if(game.keys[39] || game.keys[68]){
              if(game.player.x<=500-50){
              game.player.x+=game.player.speed;
              game.player.rendered = false;
            }

           }
           if(game.count % game.division == 0){
            game.left = !game.left;
           }

           for(i in game.enemies){
              if(game.left){

                game.enemies[i].x-=game.enemySpeed;
              }else{
                game.enemies[i].x+=game.enemySpeed;
              }
            }
        }

      function render(){
         game.contextBackground.clearRect(0,0,game.width,game.height)
         game.contextBackground.fillStyle = "white";
         for(i in game.stars){
            var star = game.stars[i];
            game.contextBackground.fillRect(star.x,star.y,star.size,star.size);
         }
         if(!game.player.rendered){
       game.contextPlayer.clearRect(0, 0, game.width, game.height);
      game.contextPlayer.drawImage(game.images[0], game.player.x, game.player.y, game.player.width, game.player.height);
      game.player.rendered = true;
         }

         for(i in game.enemies){
          var enemy = game.enemies[i];
          game.contextEnemies.clearRect(enemy.x, enemy.y, enemy.width, enemy.height);
          game.contextEnemies.drawImage(game.images[enemy.image], enemy.x, enemy.y, enemy.width, enemy.height);
         }
      }

      function loop(){
          requestAnimFrame(function(){
            loop();
        });
        update();
        render();
      }

      function initImages(paths){
        game.requiredImages = paths.length;
          for(i in paths){
              var img = new Image;
              img.src = paths[i];
              game.images[i] = img;
              game.images[i].onload = function(){
                  game.doneImages++;
              }
          }
      }

      function checkImages(){

        if(game.doneImages>=game.requiredImages){
          init();
        }
        else{
          setTimeout(function(){
            checkImages();

          },1)
        }
      }
      game.contextBackground.font = "bold 50px monaco"
      game.contextBackground.fillStyle = "white";
      game.contextBackground.fillText("loading" , game.width/2-100 ,game.height/2-25)
     initImages(["player.gif", "enemy.png", "bullet.png","Image1.png","Image2.png"])
      checkImages();
});

  window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
          window.oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
          window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
          function( callback ){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
   })();
   })();

   </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: probably some anti-aliasing glitch, better to clear the whole `game.contextEnemies` since you redraw every of the enemies at each call.

Comment: So how can i fix it? Do you see problem?

Comment: Well, IMO the best fix is to call `game.contextEnemies.clearRect(0,0,game.width,game.height)` once, just before your enemy loop.

Comment: When i use your second suggestion i get a black screen with no loading screen or anything :(

Comment: I removed it from my comment, just give @MagnusEngdal's answer a try; he best found your issue, and also has the same "better fix" that I left in my earlier comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, you clear `contextEnemies` with this

```
game.contextEnemies.clearRect(enemy.x, enemy.y, enemy.width, enemy.height);
```

The problem here is that you are clearing the square where you are about to draw the enemy, not the square where it was drawn **last time**. You need to keep track of where you drew the enemy at previous render (`enemy.x`), and clear that part.

Either you add something like `enemy.lastx` to the enemy object, to keep track of it's previous position. Or the easiest solution would be to just clear the entire `contextEnemies` as you are doing with `contextBackground`.

```
game.contextBackground.clearRect(0, 0, game.width, game.height);
game.contextEnemies.clearRect(0, 0, game.width, game.height);
```

Hope that helps. Cheers!

Comment: When i replaced the line that said   game.contextEnemies.clearRect(enemy.x, enemy.y, enemy.width, enemy.height);  to your both lines you suggested at the end. It showed the rocket ship but there were no enemies what so ever. I really dont want to track the enemies :(

Comment: @ewrwr make this clearRect() out of the for loop (before)

Comment: Thanks a Lot @Kaiido and Mangus  and  .  It worked. I just love Stack Overflow with helpfull people!!!!!

Comment: @ewrwr Add it right after you clear `contextBackground` as in my example above. First line in `render()` function. Otherwise you will clear the entire context once for each enemy.